# Will .Net 5.0 have features that .Net Core doesn't have for WCF web services?

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-core, wcf-binding, .net-5

I see the new preview version of .Net 5.0 is on Microsoft's dotnet site.
I'm curious to know, because I know they tried to merge the two frameworks (.Net Core + .Net)
into just one package, if the WCF (SOAP) calls that I didn't have in .Net Core, but had in .Net will now be available in .Net 5.0?

ex. I couldn't send documents with .Net Core using WCF/SOAP using the SVCUTIL.exe tool.
There were binding issues, etc, etc. so I had to build a separate .Net app that my .Net Core app connected called, just for sending docs.

It would be nice if I can now do it all in .Net 5.0 and get rid of the .Net project entirely!
Does anyone know if this now will be possible?

Comment: Afaik, grpc is used instead of wcf, there is no plans to reinstate wcf

Comment: hi Pavel. do you know if I can connect to WCF/SOAP services with grpc? Currently I generate a proxy file, given a url, then it creates the web service file for me to use.

Comment: Microsoft said with .NET Core 3.1, the efforts of porting API's from older platforms was *done and complete* and WCF would *not* be migrated. As far as I know, there are no plans to include more legacy technology into .NET 5

Answer (score 2):

.NET 5 is really only the next iteration of .NET Core and NOT a merger between .NET Core and .NET Framework. (.NET 5 however also merges components from mono / Xamarin into .NET Core)

This means that there is currently no significant change to the level of support for WCF hosting components in the .NET 5 timeframe.

For issues with the client-side components of WCF, watch the https://github.com/dotnet/wcf repository or open issues there.

For server-side WCF, the current suggestions are to replace them with more modern web APIs or GRPC services (do note that hosting GRPC services in IIS is blocked by Windows lacking some features  - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9020)